# Load testing with Asp.net site- issue regarding database entry

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, jmeter, load-testing

I want to load test one scenario for the load testing a ASP.net site.

There is one grid of records that contain kind of scorecards.
When user Click on view for any one record, new Tab will open with that scorecard detail. And in which user can select Review or Dispute radio button and simply submit the form.But when user click on the Submit button, one pop up comes with the OK button in it. And when user click on the OK it will close the newly open Tab(score card detail) and update/refresh the that Grid page.

So while recording of the scenario when I click on the submit button I am not getting any confirmation pop-up(as Jmeter is not able to execute Java script). and also there is no database entry for that form submission.
This scenario is working fine in normal user actions(without Jmeter).

While recording I can also see the Request recorded for Form submission but not reflected in database.

I am not sure if this is because of the limitation of the Jmeter of inability to execute Java script or something related to Proxy settings.
But after the talk with the developers they said before the java script alert, another code/method is executed for database entry. So could not figure it out what exactly the problem is SO looking for some help from you guys.

Answer (score 0):

jmeter- during its execution runs in non-ui mode while java script is used for basic validations and making the user interface comfortable

a better approach or a solution is to have a chat with the developer to disable the pop up and complete the action without a popup (or a button within browser itself in case of any dependency of button to execute the functionality) in your local environment to proceed further